# "To sound (like)" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, verbs, word-choice

The verb *sound* in English sometimes acts copulative. The definition of this sense in Merriam–Webster's dictionary is

> to make or convey an impression especially when heard
> // *it sounds good to me*
> // *you sound just like your mother*

A similar verb in English is *seem*, which is translated as **videri** in Latin. However I don't know if **audiri**, by analogy, can be used for *to sound*. **Sonare** doesn't seem to have this sense either.

In French, *avoir l'air* "to have the appearance" is used for both *to seem* and *to sound*. Are there any expression for this sense exclusively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question! You are right when saying that the English verb *sound* appears to act as a ["sensory copula"](https://web.archive.org/web/20200604002801id_/https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/A1F48C5B94F3279A2B97DE34C976E535/S1866980820000198a.pdf/div-class-title-soundscapes-in-english-and-spanish-a-corpus-investigation-of-verb-constructions-div.pdf) in some examples (e.g. 'it sounds good'; cf. the same use with other verbs: 'She looks pretty', 'It feels soft', i.a.). Similarly (but not identically), the Latin verbs *sonare* and *audire* are sometimes used with an obligatory praedicativum (aka 'subject complement'), typically in poetry. A brief treatment of the copular use of these two verbs can be found in an appendix of Section 4.97 "Copular verbs" from Pinkster (2015: 209). *The Oxford Latin Syntax* (vol. 1), where this copulative usage is attributed to Greek influence, with the meaning ‘to be called’, ‘to be spoken of (as)' (cf. Gr. ἀκούω).

> *invictus*...tua, Caesar, in urbe **sonas** (Mart. 7.6.8)
> ‘in thy city, Caesar, thou art proclaimed Unconquered.’ (Loeb transl.)

> *Felix* alius *magnusque* **sonet** (Sen. *Her. O.* 692) 'Let another be spoken of as blest and great.' (cf. Loeb transl.: 'Let another be noised abroad as blest and great')

> *rexque paterque* / **audisti** coram, nec verbo parcius absens (Hor. *Ep.* 1.7.37–8) 'and you have been called "king" and "father" to your face, nor do I stint my words behind your back.' (Loeb transl.)

> ipse *subtilis veterum iudex et callidus* **audis** (Hor. *S.* 2.7.101) 'you are called a "fine and expert critic of antiques".' (Loeb transl.)

> *Cassus* ne sacerdos **audior**? (Stat. *Theb.* 4.504). 'Am I, the priest, heard for nothing?' (Loeb transl.)